# Create a process specifying the NUMA node to run on

Tags: c++, winapi, process, launch, numa

How to launch a process in Windows on a specific NUMA node in C++?

E.g. command `start /NODE X` does this for node X. But how to achieve the same programmatically?

Comment: use [`PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PREFERRED_NODE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-updateprocthreadattribute)

Answer (score 4):

You can pass a [`STARTUPINFOEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/ns-winbase-_startupinfoexw) to [`CreateProcess()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) (enable the `EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT` flag), where the `STARTUPINFOEX` contains a pointer to a `PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST` struct that has a `PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PREFERRED_NODE` item in its list:

> The lpValue parameter is a pointer to the node number of the preferred NUMA node for the new process.

See [`InitializeProcThreadAttributeList()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-initializeprocthreadattributelist) and [`UpdateProcThreadAttribute()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-updateprocthreadattribute) to more information about building the attribute list.

Raymond Chen discusses `PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST` on his blog:

[Programmatically controlling which handles are inherited by new processes in Win32](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111216-00/?p=8873)

[Another way to create a process with attributes, maybe worse maybe better](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=4543)